# newsgroup client

Tags: iphone

I hope to develop a newsgroup client reader for iPhone.
But I can not find out any technology concern this.

Welcome any commnents

Thanks

interdev

Comment: Your question is too vague. What specifically do you need an answer for?

Answer (score 1):

- [Wikipedia description of usenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet)
- [Usenet protocol overview](http://people.dsv.su.se/~jpalme/e-mail-book/usenet-news.html)
- [Official RFC describing the NNTP protocol](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc977.html)
- iPhone development getting started: [1](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/05/how-to-get-started-with-iphone-dev/), [2](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Burnette/?p=681), [3](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/100-iPhone_Development_Quick_Start/iphone_development_quick_start.html)

Comment: Does cocoa has any sdk for this？

Comment: No, as far as I know there is no built in NNTP client in the Cocoa libraries.